# Is there a way to make 'expandRowByClick' executable only if I click a certain part of the row in Ant Design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am trying to develop an expandable table row that uses Ant Design's built in `expandRowByClick` function. The function determines 'Whether to expand row by clicking anywhere in the whole row', but I wanted to see if there is a way to get this to apply only to a certain part of the row. I am incorporating a switch on each row that will determine whether or not to include or omit that concealed by the un-expanded row. Currently, when I click the toggle the function I execute for `onExpandedRowsChange` is executed and the toggle switch's function is skipped entirely.

I have tried getting determining whether or not I am clicking the toggle by find the `event.target`. But since React is meant to put HTML elements to the DOM using JS rather than traditional JS manipulating HTML elements on the DOM directly, I just get `<react></react>`. I dove in pretty deep to all the attributes within the react event but couldn't find anything of use.

I figured if there was some way I could determine that I was clicking the toggle and not just the row I could run a conditional in my `onExpandedRowsChange` function that evaluates whether or not to continue with the `onExpandedRowsChange` function or to `e.stopPropagation()` and run the toggle function. But this potential solution hasn't panned out thus far.

I also tried using a `ref` for the toggle switches so I could try to grab the HTML from `this.refs...` but when I try to `.bind(this...` on the function it doesn't execute.

Here is my table:

```
<Table
            rowClassName={record => record.diminishingReturn ? style.driverRow : style.folderRow}
            className={style.scnTable}
            columns={columns}
            expandRowByClick
            bordered
            defaultExpandAllRows={me.state.expandAll}
            size="middle"
            rowKey={'activityGroupName'}
            dataSource={categorizedData}
            pagination={false}
            loading={me.props.data.get('loading')}
            expandedRowKeys={this.props.expandedRowKeys}
            onExpandedRowsChange={(rows) => { this.checkExpandedRows(rows)}}
          />
```

The row with the toggle switch:

```
<div className={ this.props.expandedRowKeys.includes(r.activityGroupName) ? style.folderExpanded : null}> 
   <div style={{position: 'absolute', left: 10 + 'px', top: 10 + 'px', zIndex: 1000}} ref='yes'>
      <input id={r.activityGroupName} className={styles.inputYo} onChange={me.onOmitChange.bind(me, 'budgetPreference', r)} type="checkbox" checked={!!r.enabled}/>
      <label htmlFor={r.activityGroupName} className={styles.labelYo} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>Toggle</label>
   </div>
   <h2 style={{marginLeft: 40 + 'px'}}><Icon type="folder" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{r.activityGroupName}&nbsp;({r.children.length})</h2>
   <Icon type={'caret-down'} style={ this.state.expandedRowKeys.includes(r.activityGroupName) ? {transform: 'rotate(180deg)'}: null} />
</div>
```

The row expand function:

```
checkExpandedRows = (rows) =>{
   event.stopPropagation()
   this.props.checkExpandedRows(rows)
}
```

And the toggle function:

```
onOmitChange = (x, y, z) =>{
  if (document.getElementById(y.activityGroupName).checked == true) {
    this.onEnableDisableRowForOptimization(y, "enable")
  } else if (document.getElementById(y.activityGroupName).checked == false){
    this.onEnableDisableRowForOptimization(y, "disable")
  }
}
```

The `checkExpandedRows` function should work but only if any part of the row the than the toggle switch is clicked. If the toggle is clicked, then stop the row expansion and execute the `onOmitChange` function. I haven't included the conditional in the row expand function because I'm not sure what should be written for it.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the row to expand when on click except for when one column particular column is clicked?

Comment: I should have clarified, the row is essentially just one column. I conditionally render the columns based on a data attribute, if that attribute is not present, then render the one column row with a col-span of 4 and the others a col-span of 0. This is meant to render a row that indicates the type of data the other rows (the ones that show when its expanded) is present. I could try to put the toggle in it’s own small column but wouldn’t the whole row still be clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. With `rowExpandable` just return `true` or `false` based on you condition.

`rowExpandable: record => record.attachments.length > 0`